# Last screen seen on cursor position after moving to a new screen

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I'm running `Qt 5.5.1` on my `embedded Linux` machine. When a mouse is connected the cursor is visible and work as expected, but, when I'm pressing on a widget to move to another screen the new screen is presented with the old screen view inside a small square (mouse background at the time of the press). Example:

[image: Before. Two tabs when the left one is active]

[image: After. When pressing on the right tab the small square appers]

It seems like it's a rendering issue. Your help is most welcome.

Comment: Which QPA is used?

Comment: Hi @FrankMeerkötter, thanks for your help. I searched A way to get my QPA and didn't found one.